# VM daisy chain with external Pi

Tags: virtual-machines

This is for an assignment that I am working on. Pi is external while CentRelay, WinSvrRelay and CentClient are all VMs created using VMWare Workstation Pro 16.

```
------          -------------        ---------------        --------------
| Pi |<-------->| CentRelay |<------>| WinSvrRelay |<------>| CentClient |
------  bridged -------------  LAN1  ---------------  LAN2  --------------
```

Pi has wifi connected to my home network with firewall disabled and masquerading to provide internet connection and a bridged ethernet connection to my host.

```
WiFi IP: 192.168.0.99
Bridged: 172.168.1.1/24
```

CentRelay is using CentOS 8 Stream, firewall disabled and masquerading.

```
Bridged: 172.168.1.2/24
LAN 1: 192.168.2.1/27
```

WinSvrRelay is using Windows Server 2019, firewall disabled with RRAS set up for LAN routing and added NAT routing protocol.

```
LAN 1: 192.168.2.2/27
LAN 2: 192.168.2.33/27
```

CentClient is using CentOS 8 Stream, firewall disabled.

```
LAN 2: 192.168.2.34/27
```

All the VMs have internet connection but when I try to ping it is all one way. CentClient/WinSvrRelay can ping the Pi but the Pi can't ping them back. The Pi can ping CentRelay and CentRelay can ping the Pi, so I used Wireshark and noticed that there is no answer to ARP request when the Pi tries to ping WinSvrRelay. I have tried adding a route from CentRelay to WinSvrRelay with:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.32/27 dev ens224
```

This did nothing to help and I was wondering if I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated and thank you! First time posting on forums so if I am missing any required information please let me know.

Comment: Why do you use NAT if the goal is end to end connectivity?

Comment: I initially only used LAN routing but CentClient wasn't getting internet connectivity then I watched a video on youtube and tried doing it this method and it worked. Would this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is the cause of your problem. Set up routing and ip forwarding on all systems.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you've configured masquerading NAT. This breaks end to end connectivity, but allows many systems to hide behind a single IP.

You should configure each VM to act as a router, without masquerading. In addition, you have to tell each router in your system how to reach the various networks you're using.

The Pi should have the following routing table:

| DST | Next hop |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.2.0/24 | 172.168.1.2 |

This tells your Pi that the entire 192.168.2.0/24 subnet can be reached by sending a packet to 172.168.1.2. The Pi doesn't need to know that the subnet is further subnettet downstream; routes can be aggregated.

The command to add such a route on Linux would be `ip route add to 192.168.2.0/24 via 172.168.1.2`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Please accept and consider upvoting the answer if it was helpful.